# jquery toggle link not working in internet explorer

Tags: jquery

in internet explorer i do get this when i click on a link with javascript and query:

```
[object Object]
```

the link is:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#bla').toggle();">
```

thanks!

edit:
regarding the answers so far: i can not use the recommended jquery way because i am autogenerating the links with a server-side script (there are actually several thousands on the page).

Comment: this is not `jQuery` way?? u r doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its because IE tries to follow the link to the object bla. A better why to do this would be to set the onclick of the anchor element to call a function.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleElement();">
```

Or an even better way would be to add an event listener in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="linkId">Link</a>
```

and script is

```
$('#linkId')click(function(){
   $('#bla').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the right way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){  
            jQuery('a#linkId').click(function() {
                            jQuery('#bla').toggle();
           });
    });
</script>
```